How to get newly created and tradeable fungible token data on solana
I am totally new to solana development and playing around with web3.js. I am currently trying to access data for of newly created and tradeable tokens. I am subscribing to solana's token program logs for this purpose. For each transaction, I am checking if the transaction instruction is InitializeMint, then getting the data of that transaction using getTransaction method. Below is my code
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as borsh from 'borsh';
import bs58  from "bs58";

// Initialize connection to Solana
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), {
    commitment: 'finalized',
    wsEndpoint: 'wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'
});

// Solana Token Program ID
const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA');

// Function to subscribe to token program logs
async function subscribeToTokenLogs() {
    try {
        // Subscribe to logs related to the Solana Token Program
        connection.onLogs(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, (logs, context) => {
            logs.logs.forEach(log => {
                const instructions = log.split('\n');
                instructions.forEach(async (instruction) => {
                    if (instruction.includes('Instruction: InitializeMint')) {
                        const { transaction } = await connection.getTransaction(logs.signature, {
                            maxRetries: 2, // Number of times to retry on failure (optional)
                            commitment: 'confirmed', // Desired commitment level (optional),
                            maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
                            "encoding": "jsonParsed"
                        });
                        console.log('Transaction Signature:', logs.signature);
                        console.log('Transaction ', transaction, '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n')
                        //console.log('Transaction:', Buffer.from(bs58.decode(transaction.message.instructions[transaction.message.instructions.length - 1].data)).toString(), "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                        // Process the transaction further if needed
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error subscribing to token program logs:', error);
    }
}

Below is the output that I see in my console
{
 value: undefined,
  type: 'array',
  refinement: undefined,
  key: 'accounts',
  path: [ 'meta', 'innerInstructions', 0, 'instructions', 0, 'accounts' ],
  branch: [
    {
      blockTime: 1715283987,
      meta: [Object],
      slot: 264819872,
      transaction: [Object],
      version: 0
    },
    {
      computeUnitsConsumed: 75065,
      err: null,
      fee: 10000,
      innerInstructions: [Array],
      logMessages: [Array],
      postBalances: [Array],
      postTokenBalances: [Array],
      preBalances: [Array],
      preTokenBalances: [],
      rewards: [],
      status: [Object]
    },
    [ [Object], [Object] ],
    { index: 2, instructions: [Array] },
    [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    {
      parsed: [Object],
      program: 'spl-token',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      stackHeight: 2
    },
    undefined
  ],
  failures: [Function (anonymous)]
}

Now, I don't know how to proceed, where to read the data I am looking for. How can I read the data related to newly created and tradeable fungible tokens in solana?
Am I on the right path? Or should I take another route?
